# Power Query to extract JSON parameter values from the data

Tags: array, power-query, json

Hope you are doing well!...I am trying to split the different parameter values for just the correct ,added and removed codes at a vbillid level..In the attached excel file the column codemap has the json from which the codes (belonging to removed, revised or added need to be extracted) from the different coding parameter categories such as cpt drg, modifiers, secondaryDiagnosis, principalDiagnosis, secondaryProcedure, observationhours , dischargeStatus ,principalprocedure,hcpcs

...Can you please help me here... The detailed question is here..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68159800/postgres-sql-query-to-summarize-errors-data

Thanks,
Arun

Comment: Hi Team...Any help on this would be much appreciated!

Comment: If you are still looking for an answer, I suggest you edit your question to include a valid JSON string. Your question is about extracting parameter values from a JSON, but your linked question does not include a valid JSON string.  You might get help from some (like myself) who do not have fiddle.